# export data from current search into excel in Laravel?

Tags: excel, laravel

After search the search result is displayed in the screen. That content I must download as excel.

Controller.php

```
public function searchList(Request $request)
{
    $fleet_issues = FleetIssue::all();
    $list = FleetIssue::orderBy('check_at', 'desc');
    $directory  = FleetManagementHelper :: getFleetIssueImageDirectory();
    $fleet_issue_type = FleetIssueType::all();
    $vehicle_class = VehicleClass::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $location= Location::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();


         if( $request->plate_number){
             $list = $list->where('plate_number', $request->plate_number );
        }


        if( $request->branch){
            $list = $location->where('id', $request->branch );
        }

        if( $request->nric){
            $list = $list->where('nric',$request->nric);                       
        }

        if( $request->fleet_issue_type_id){
            $list = $list->where('fleet_issue_type_id',$request->fleet_issue_type_id);                       
        }

    $list = $list->paginate(20);
  view('pages.control_panel.view_issues',compact('list','fleet_issues','directory','fleet_issue_type','vehicle_class','location'));
}
```

Below is to download the excel file from the Export.php

```
public function downloadExcel()
{  
return Excel::download(new Export,'List.xlsx');
 }
```

Below is the Export.php..How can i filter search here??

Export.php

```
Use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;


class Export implements FromView,ShouldAutoSize,WithHeadings, WithEvents
 {
  public function headings(): array
 {
     return [
         'Reservation Number', 'NRIC/Passport', 'Vehicle Model','Branch','Date of Checking','Issues'
     ];
 }

public function view() : View
{
    $vehicle_class = VehicleClass::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $location= Location::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $fleet_issue_type = FleetIssueType::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $list = FleetIssue::orderBy('check_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
    $directory  = FleetManagementHelper :: getFleetIssueImageDirectory(); 

if(  $this->vehicle_model){
$list = $list->where('vehicle_model', $this->vehicle_model);
}
 return view('pages.control_panel.fleet_management.fleet_issues.list_fleet_issues',compact('vehicle_class','location','fleet_issue_type','list','directory'));

}
```

How can i export my result from search to excel?How i can filter the searchlist in Export??How to passing current request variable in export like doing in the controller?

Comment: You will have to use the current request variable in the Export class. All the parameters that are used to create the query should be included in the queries from Export class.

Comment: how to include current request variable in Export? Is it same like controller request variable?

Comment: you can use `request()` helper. `request()->all()` will return all the params.